# How to copy a dictionary with a special value?

Tags: python

The data:

```
mydict = {'__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'Foo' objects>,\
 '__doc__': None, 'name': 'Guido'}
```

I am attempting to make a copy:

```
import copy
copy_dict = copy.deepcopy(mydict)
```

unexpected error reports:

```
TypeError: can't pickle getset_descriptor objects
```

if `dict = {'name':'Guido'}`,it works

```
>>> copy.deepcopy(dict)
{'name': 'Guido'}
```

What's the problem?

Comment: You can stringify the dict values before pickling, to ensure they can all be pickled. This, obviously, will potentially cause problems when unpickling (depending on your further goals); but so will trying to pickle a getset_descriptor.

Comment: Something has gone wrong in your code long before the attempt to copy this dict.  You should never have a `__weakref__` attribute separate from the object it originally came from; it's not meaningful in any other context.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the value of your dictionary in quotes . Below works find in python2.7

```
>>> mydict = {'__weakref__': "<attribute '__weakref__' of 'Foo' objects>",\
 '__doc__': None, 'name': 'Guido'}
>>> copy_dict = copy.deepcopy(mydict)
>>> copy_dict
{'__weakref__': "<attribute '__weakref__' of 'Foo' objects>", '__doc__': None, 'name': 'Guido'}
>>>
```

Comment: Hi, what is wrong in my answer. In python2.7 it works fine